# Whats the use of binding all function to window object?

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to JS and I have a doubt here. Lets say I have a function like this:

```
function test(a) {}
```

that is accessible via `window`, so doing so:

```
window.test
```

I can call the function. But whats the purpose of binding all functions to `window` object? Is there any advantage?

I have few questions:

1. When this `window` object get created? Is it per page?
2. Is there any function, which won't be bind to `window`
3. `window` can access even private variables, functions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window object is the browser window (1). Or nowadays the tab. It's a system object set by the browser. All functions and expressions that are created in the `global scope` are bound to the window object (2). JavaScript cannot create private variables like *c* or *java* does. However when a value is in a `closure` it cannot be accessed through the window object (3).

**Closure**: A function with it's own scope. Closures allow the use of private variables only available to the function

Consider this code:

```
var createClosure = function() {
  var a = 0;
  return function() {
    a++;
    return a;
  };
};

var a = createClosure();
a(); //displays 1
a(); //displays 2
```

Now there are two `a`'s. One `a` is a private variable only accessible by `createClosure()`, the other `a` is a property of the `window` object (globally accessible) and is a reference to the returned function in `createClosure`. You cannot globally access the first `a`.

Within a function you need to use the `var` keyword when defining variables. If not they become global.

Comment: therefore ***it is** private* to the function scope. So are private the Object members created by a constructor. And thanks to the *prototypal* Object - Oriented nature of the language makes it even more exciting.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan You are absolutely right about the constructor. Thanks for reminding me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Window is the global scope, so doing

```
var something = 'hi';
// or
window.something = 'hi';
// product the same result.
```

Generally adding variables to the global scope is considered bad, and you should use closure to create object/modules so the number of globals you create is kept to a minimum. i.e.

```
var myModule = (function () {

  var something; // private, only accessable in this function

  return {
    someOtherThing : 'some value'; 
    // public, accessed with myModule.someOtherThing
  }

})();
```

In the above example only window.myModule would be global, inner variables/functions would not

Answer (score 0):

Every variable or function is accessible with window "keyword" because window is a superglobal variable in javascript.

1. window object refers to your window.
2. Nope. You can call any function with/without window (without window if it is in scope)
3. How do you create private variables in javascript? If you are talking about functions stored in a variable with 'new' keyword, then no, window object cannot access those 'private' variables.